# Appium run non shell ADB command

Tags: appium, appium-android

This doc shows instructions how to run adb **shell** commands on Appium clients.
https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-shell/

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
args.put("command", "echo");
args.put("args", Lists.newArrayList("arg1", "arg2"));
String output = driver.executeScript("mobile: shell", args);
assert output.equals("arg1 arg2");
```

I want to run the `adb push` command:

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
args.put("command", "push");
args.put("args", Lists.newArrayList("./app/images.zip", "/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.demoapp/files/images.zip"));
String output = driver.executeScript("mobile: shell", args);
assert output.equals("arg1 arg2");
```

However, the adb push command is not supported in the **shell** environment.

Any help?

I know something should change on the driver.executeScript("**mobile: shell**", args); Don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the [Appium Push File functionality](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/files/push-file/index.html)?

```
driver.pushFile("./app/images.zip", new File("/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.demoapp/files/images.zip"));
```

Comment: `driver.pushFile()` has some restrictions. Please see issue: https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1840